# How to replace an incorrect variable name throughout your code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Let's say I create a variable name called `test` and I use it a bunch of times in my code. I later want to change the name to `TestObj`.

Can I do this in one shot?

Comment: Why not try google? or right clicking? or literally anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio, select the varialbe and click Edit -> Refactor -> Rename or Ctrl R R.

Comment: this is correct, if it's not working then try doing F2 as answered by @Danny Chen

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R

That's the shortcut for rename.  Which should rename the variable in all references.

Comment: Ctrl+R doesn't seem to work.  I can right click and say rename and that works.

Comment: With your cursor over the variable name, in either the declaration, or a reference, hold down the ctrl key and tap 'R' twice.  You can now type the new name and hit enter to finish.

Answer (score 2):

Select the variable then Ctrl+ R R and you can select if you're gonna replace all variable in the solution or just in the class you're into

Answer (score 2):

Instead of CtrlRR, I use `F2`, the same as renaming a file in windows.